# Swift JSONSerialization.data crashing

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a example 2 struct below,

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let a: String
    let b: [Department]
}

struct Department: Codable {
    let bb: String
}

let dict = ["a": "aa", "b": [Department(bb: "D")]] as [String : Any]
// Crashing here
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

And I try create Person object from dictionary, I get a crash Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)', I understand Codable is Swift type JSONSerialization.data will not accept, how do I convert that. I don't want to manually build Person object

Comment: Why not use Codable?

Comment: How do you go from Person to dict?

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot encode a dictionary with the type: [String:Any], because protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Encodable', so in your example you must create two dictionaries of two different types: [String:String] and [String:Department].

For encoding a Person instance you need to do:

```
let person = Person(a="example", b=Department(bb="example"))
let personData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(person)
```

For decoding a Person instance you need to do:

```
let decodedPerson = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: personData)
```

If you receives a JSON object you can decode it like this:

```
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: .prettyPrinted)
let decodedPerson = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Don't use `try ?` for decoding.  This is a horrible pattern that pervades json decoding examples and results in about 90% of JSONDecoder questions on SO that wouldn't need to be asked if proper `do/try/catch` was used to catch and print the helpful errors that JSONDecoder provides.